# Cannot access media files from woocommerce folder

Tags: wordpress, video, woocommerce, media

I have developed a addon of woocommerce to upload video as a downloadable product and the customer is able to view that video in a popup rather downloading it from My Account > Downloads area.

I am facing issue that when i am trying to load video uploaded in `/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/my-video.mp4`, it gives me error of 403 i.e I don't have access to the file of the folder.

When i compared the file and folder permissions with the default folders of wp then i find that the folders and files inside `woocommerce_uploads` have same permission.

I searched for the solution but didn't find anything yet.

Can anyone suggest me that how i can access this file so that it will load inside a popup.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`woocommerce_uploads` . folder will be containing an `.htaccess` file with `deny from all` inside it, please remove those texts to make those files publicly accessible.

Comment: Ok let me try that.

Comment: that makes a file publicly available.